# Effects of Modafinil

Tags: medications, sleep, fatigue, insomnia, energy

As someone who suffers from chronic insomnia and often has to get things done during the day without much or any sleep at all, I would like to know from those experienced what the effects are of Modafinil and other wakefulness drugs before trying them myself. I guess my questions are mainly:

1. How does one feel after taking Modafinil?
2. If I go without sleep for a night, will Modafinil give me an energy boost for the subsequent day?
3. Does Modafinil have similar effects as energy drinks or other stimulants in that they increase your heart rate and can make you feel nervous?

I have tried drugs like cocaine and amphetamine and although they do the job and keep you awake without sleepiness I don't like them at all because of how they alter your mood and cause depression when the effects wear off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for subjective opinion, so that's what you're going to get. I've taken it a few times and here are my answers to your questions:

1. Mentally alert and awake.
2. A mental energy boost, yes. Physical, not so much.
3. No, it's not a general stimulant like amphetamines. It makes you mentally alert and wakeful, but there is no cardiac stimulation, nervousness, etc.

You can find full drug info including effects, side effects and precautions [here.](https://www.drugs.com/sfx/modafinil-side-effects.html)

Comment: How long do the effects last and once they dissipate does one hit a wall of excruciating exhaustion after a sleepless night?

Comment: @user651351 That's going to depend on the person and how sleep deprived they are. Modafinil will keep you awake and alert, but once it wears off you're going to be as tired as you would have been without it. You won't be more or less tired because of the Modafinil. Effects last about 12 hours.

Comment: @user651351 My personal experience is that If you use it every day for a long time (months) it can mentally drain you. It locks you to things you start doing right after you took it and you literally become prisoner of them.